# I'm trying to get my bot to post messages in a channel it just created. How to retrieve the id of a channel that has just been automatically created?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The goal is to make a bot that deals with postulations. He needs to create a channel for the applicant that only him (and the admins) can see, that part is ok.

He must then ask a series of questions automatically in the channel he has just created for the applicant.
And that's where I'm stuck.
I can't get the id of the channel automatically created.

(I'm new to programming, please be kind.)

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(prefix = "!", intents=intents)
guild = discord.Guild

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} est connecté !')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!startApply'):

        guild = message.guild
        Officier = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Officier")

        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            message.author : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            Officier: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)

        }

        await guild.create_text_channel(f'Apply {message.author}', overwrites=overwrites)



client.run('my_token')
```

I tried to put all the possible arguments, I can't send a message in the channel that the bot has just created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_text_channel()` function automatically returns the channel, which is a `TextChannel` object, that the bot created.

So, to send a message in that channel, just do:

```py
# ...
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(...)
await channel.send("...")
```

Hope this helps.